# Moving decimal from the right in PHP

Tags: php, math

I have large numbers and their decimals points. Here are some examples and what should return:

```
Number: 300000
Decimals: 8
Should return: 0.00300000

Number: 700000000
Decimals: 8 
Should return: 7


Number: 800000000
Decimals: 6
Should return: 800
```

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
substr($number, 0, abs($decimals + 1))
```

But it returns 0 if the number of decimals is superior to the number of digits in the number (example one returns 0).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Number/10^Decimals. How many zeroes should the result have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Divide by 10 to the power of the number of decimals:

```
$result = $number / (10 ** $decimals);
```

Comment: That's great, thank you, was way out of my depth on this one.

Comment: Glad to help @Callombert!

Answer (score 1):

Divide by ten to the power of  decimals?

```
$n = 700000000;
$d = 8;

Echo $n/pow(10,$d);
```

https://3v4l.org/MdoW1