# divide a number by x decmial places

Tags: php, math, division

Say I have a large number, 1234567. In PHP, is there a way that I could divide this number by x decimal places?

i.e:

```
divide(1234567, 0) // returns 1234567
divide(1234567, 3) // returns 1234.567
divide(1234567, 5) // returns 12.34567
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving decimal from the right in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143473/moving-decimal-from-the-right-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to shift the comma, which is equivalent to multiplication by powers of `10`, including no shift as multiplication by `1 = pow(10, 0)`
This is easily done by:

```php
123*pow(10, 0); //returns 123
123*pow(10, -3); //returns 0.123
123*pow(10, -1); //returns 12.3
```

Note that this even allows negative numbers.